# when you pass by reference are we changing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function:

```
filterList(event) {
  var updateList = this.state.initialItems;

  updateList = updateList.filter(function(item) {
                  return item.search(event.target.value) !== -1;
               });

  this.setState({currentItems: updateList });
}
```

If we are passing by reference isn't updateList and this.state.initialItems pointing to the same thing?

How would I make a copy of this.state.initialItems?

Comment: The `filter` method returns a new array in itself so no, you're no longer pointing to the reference.

Comment: `updateList.filter` returns a new array. After `updateList.filter`, updateList does not point to `state.initialItems`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If we are passing by reference isn't updateList and
>   this.state.initialItems pointing to the same thing?

No. You're returning an entirely new array (per [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)):

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

Answer (score 1):

To make a new array without reference you can also use spread operator.
example:
var updateList = [...this.state.initialItems];

Above code will make a new array which do not have reference of the previous one.